# Mariadb Regular Expression - Check if string contains a prefix and at least 1 digit

Tags: regex, mariadb

I am trying to find a code from a column in a table than contains a sequence of letters and numbers.  They code contains a prefix `^AB` then a sequence of either just letters `A OR AAA` or letters or numbers `1 OR A1 OR 1A`

I need a regular expression that that returns YES/NO if the characters following the prefix contains a number

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT 'AB1AX' RLIKE '^AB[A-Z0-9]+(?=\\d)$';
SELECT 'ABA1X' RLIKE '^AB[A-Z0-9]+(?=\\d)$';
SELECT 'AB09'  RLIKE '^AB[A-Z0-9]+(?=\\d)$';
```

However this does not match.

Comment: Try `SELECT 'AB09'  RLIKE '^AB(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+$';` or just `SELECT 'AB09'  RLIKE '^AB[A-Z]*[0-9][A-Z0-9]*$';`

Comment: What version of MariaDB.  Part of your regexp requires at least 10.0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not mach any string, it will never match, because you require a digit after the end of string.

You need to use

```
^AB[A-Z]*[0-9][A-Z0-9]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mYHDDR/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `AB` - the "hard-coded" prefix
- `[A-Z]*` - 0+ uppercase ASCII chars
- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `[A-Z0-9]*` - 0+ uppercase letters/digits
- `$` - end of string.